# Get suffixes in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, c-strings, suffix

I'm trying to get the suffixes of an entered string, but i'm getting the prefixes how can I make to fix it?

The expected result for example with an entry string "Hello" is:

```
Hello 
ello
ell
el
e
```

Now is returning:

```
Hello
Hell
Hel
He
H
```

Thanks

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **suffix;

void panic(char *m) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", m);
  exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int n, i;

  if (argc != 2)
    panic("wrong parameters");

  n = strlen(argv[1]);

  suffix = (char **)malloc(n * sizeof(char *));

  if (suffix == NULL)
    error("Memoria no disponible");

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    suffix[i] = (char *)malloc((n + 1 - i) * sizeof(char));
    if (suffix[i] == NULL)
      error("Memoria no disponible");

    sprintf(suffix[i], "%s", argv[1]);
    argv[1][n - 1 - i] = '\0';
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%d %s\n", i, suffix[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give expected outputs for given inputs. Also your code cannot be compiled. Fix it.

Comment: The given input could be any string, for example "hello" and the expected output is:
Hello
ello
ell
el
e

Comment: Like Eraklon said fix your code first. There are multiple problems: No headers, no definition of suffix var, no end of main, ...

Comment: Now i fixed the code. Thnks!

Comment: still problems, error needs to become perror and what are you trying to do with `n.argv[1][n-1-i]`. Are you tring to use classes in C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just substitute these two statements

```
sprintf(suffix[i], "%s", argv[1]);
argv[1][n - 1 - i] = '\0';
```

for this one statement

```
sprintf(suffix[i], "%s", argv[1] + i );
```

Comment: Tiny improvement: change `+ i` to `+ i * sizeof(char)`

Comment: @Garo This is redundant and moreover confusing because sizeof( char ) is always equal to 1. Here is used the pointer arithmetic so it is much better to write  argv[1] + i

Comment: True, but i usually do this in case the code later has to be changed and you are no longer working with char's but with other types (e.g. a struct that contains both the char and some extra info)

Comment: @Garo If you have a pointer as for example int *p; then the expression p + 1 is not the same as p + sizeof( int ). So you should not use sizeof( char ) in the pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Use Vlad from Moscow answer.

Something related you should now, only read `argc` and `argv`, never overwrite them. Although in theory you can do this, in practice it's both useless and dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Should always keep the code/logic as simple as you can.

The following proposed code can be halted with `<ctrl-c>` and/or `EOF`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char buffer[ 256 ];

    // get the string
    while( fgets( buffer, sizeof( buffer ), stdin ) )
    {
        //output string, dropping leading char at each loop iteration
        size_t length = strlen( buffer );

        for( size_t i=0; i<length; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%s\n", &buffer[i] );
        }
    }
}
```

here is a typical run of the program:

Note: the first line is from the user entering the string.

```
this is a string
this is a string

his is a string

is is a string

s is a string

 is a string

is a string

s a string

 a string

a string

 string

string

tring

ring

ing

ng

g
```

Comment: Be carefull ! This code does something different. It reads from STDIN instead of the 1st argument.